# Python - Searching 2 excel sheets for Data and then extracting a data label

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am very new to programming, had to learn to make a portion of my PhD project actually do-able, but after getting my python code to pull data from a website and write it to a excel file, I am a bit lost on the next part.

I have my excel file and a secondary file that was provided. I am trying to search between the two files (both of which have an 'address', and once matched, pull a label (under category) from the provided file and input this to myfile. Or if this is easier just write the results to an entirely new excel file.

'myfile'

`#|   Address                                            |
1 | 21 Abbotsford Street Falkirk FK2 7NH                 |
2 | Police Station Commissioner Street Bo'ness EH51 9AF  |
3 | 4 Riverview Terrace Bo'ness EH51 9ED                 |`

Outcome file

`#|   Address                                            |Category
1 | 21 Abbotsford Street Falkirk FK2 7NH                 |  A
2 | Police Station Commissioner Street Bo'ness EH51 9AF  |  B
3 | 4 Riverview Terrace Bo'ness EH51 9ED                 |  A`

The issue that I am having is that the two files 'Address' data is not in any particular order, so how would I go about taking the address from myfile, searching it in the provided file, pulling the 'Category' , and then combing the address/category into the outcome file (or even just adding the 'Category' into myfile.

Also extremely sorry if this is not clear at all, I tried my best to properly word it, but thanks for any advice or even what I could look into as an extension to help with this.  :)

Comment: In my opinion it's got to be easier to work with the files outside of Excel so you can use `pd.read_excel()` to get them into `DataFrame`s and then merge on the address.

Answer (score 0):

Simply run a left join [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) which matches **exact** values of *Address*:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_excel('myFile.xlsx', sheetname=0)          # ASSUMING DATA IN FIRST SHEET
df2 = pd.read_excel('OtherFile.xlsx', sheetname=0)       # ASSUMING DATA IN FIRST SHEET

outcomedf = pd.merge(df1, df2[['Address', 'Category']], on='Address', how='left')
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not completely sure if you are trying to combine both files into one and check for address duplicates or if you are trying to check if the addresses in myfiles are contained in the second file, so I have tried to provide both below.

**If you want to combine and compare both files:**

```
import pandas as pd

# Reads myfile Excel file to new data frame
df1 = pd.read_excel("C:/folder/myfile.xlsx")
# Reads second file (a .csv in this example) to new data frame
df2 = pd.read_csv("C:/folder/secondfile.csv")

# Creates a third data frame containing df1 and df2
df3 = df1.append(df2)
# Checks for duplicates and creates a new column labeling which are duplicates
df3["duplicate"] = df3.duplicated(subset="Address", keep=False)
# Removes all but the first duplicate in the Address column
df3 = df3.drop_duplicates(subset="Address")

# Writes df3 to Excel file
df3.to_excel("C:/folder/outcomefile.xlsx", index=False)
```

*Note: This will only work if both files have the same columns*

**If you want to check if the addresses in myfile are duplicated in the second file, then add a duplicates column to myfile and print to new Excel file:**

```
import pandas as pd

# Reads myfile Excel file to new data frame
df1 = pd.read_excel("C:/folder/myfile.xlsx")
# Reads second file (a .csv in this example) to new data frame
df2 = pd.read_csv("C:/folder/secondfile.csv")

# Checks if addresses in myfile (df1) are duplicated in second file (df2)
# Then adds duplicate column to myfile
df1["duplicate"] = df1["Address"].isin(df2["Address"])

# Writes edited myfile data frame to new Excel file
df1.to_excel("C:/folder/outcomefile.xlsx", index=False)
```

*Note: both will only match **exact** addresses*

Hope this helps, if you need anything different let me know!

Comment: Thanks for both the options... Unfortunately, I found an error in the supplied file, as it is an incomplete reference to use. I am now going to have to use a web-based search from myfile addresses and then hopefully extract results that way. Hopeful thinking on my part that it would just be two excel files to use! But again thanks for both codes, I am sure that they will come in handy for me once I have the new code/search program figured out